# gpg --import fails with no valid OpenPGP data found 2

Tags: unix, openpgp

I'm getting the error below while I'm trying to import `.pub` file in Unix box.

> ```
> Error...gpg no valid openpgp data found. gpg total number processed 0
> using Command. >gpg --import cv0_intf_rsa.pub
> ```

*I'm new so I don't know what other information you may need to help me*

Comment: Could you tell us a little more? What are the steps you followed? **edit your question** please; read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: there is a file like pub_key.txt that file having public key using for encrypting file. And i want to import this file in gnupgp directory ,but am getting error as show below:Error...gpg no valid openpgp data found. gpg total number processed 0